# error while creating the app with create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I am starting the work on react but when I create a react app by using npm create-react-app myapp . it show the error which is

```
Creating a new React app in D:\practise\react\myapp.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...


PS D:\practise\react> npm create-app-app myapp
Unknown command: "create-app-app"

To see a list of supported npm commands, run:
  npm help
PS D:\practise\react> npm create-react-app myapp
Unknown command: "create-react-app"

To see a list of supported npm commands, run:
  npm help
PS D:\practise\react> npm install create-react-app myapp
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'myapp@0.0.0-1',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '0.8.x' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.14.0', npm: '8.3.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
npm WARN deprecated connect@2.30.2: connect 2.x series is deprecated
npm WARN deprecated tar@2.2.2: This version of tar is no longer supported, and will not receive security updates. Please upgrade asap.

added 155 packages, and audited 156 packages in 17s

4 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

25 vulnerabilities (3 low, 5 moderate, 17 high)
```

I am unable to find the problem can someone give me the instruction which thing I did wrong.

Comment: Look a little closer at [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app). It's using `npx`, not `npm`

Answer (score -1):

for creating a new React app use the following command
before using this command make sure your Node version is 14 or above. to check your node version type `node --version` on your terminal.

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

now you are typing npm instead of npx. you can follow [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html) for more details.